# Why use do-while(true)?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while

```cpp
do {
  ...
} while (true);
```

What is meant by `true` in this example?

Example:

```cpp
do {
    cout << "  1-basic arithmetic operations  " << endl;
    cout << "  2-summation  " << endl;
    cout << "  3-Exit " <<endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice: " << endl;
    cin >> main_choice;
    switch(main_choice){
        case 1:
            operation();
            break;
        case 2:
            summation();
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Exiting program. Goodbye!" << endl; 
            return 0;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid choice. Please try again." << endl;
    }
} while (true);
```

Comment: This example is just an infinite loop. `do...while` does have a semantic difference from `for` and `while`, just not in this case.

Comment: `do { ... } while (true);`, and `while (true) { ... }`, and `for(;;) { ... }` and `loop: ... goto loop;` all do the same thing.

Comment: Stay a while. Stay FOREVER! Muhuhahahahahahahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: I don't know if I got the best dupe, but somewhere out there is a dupe.

Comment: @Rogue It's not infinite, it has at least one exit point at `case 3:` `return`.

Comment: The `true` is the continuation condition, and since it is always `true`, the loop as a whole is another way to loop forever, since your loop body actually has an observable effect.  Your particular loop explicitly terminates the loop (by returning from the containing function) if value `3` is entered by the user, .

Answer (score 1):

When using a do-while construction, you employ the following syntax:

```
do{
<body>
} while(<condition>)
```

Here, `<condition>` represents a boolean expression, meaning it can evaluate to either true or false. If the condition is true, the instructions within `<body>` are executed, and the loop continues. If the condition is false, the loop terminates, and the program proceeds with instructions outside the loop's body.

With the do-while construction, you always execute the `<body>` once, before evaluating the condition.

If `<condition>` is true, you are writing an infinite loop.

Comment: The OP's loop is not infinite, since one of the cases has a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop repeatedly executes the body until the condition is `false`. The difference between `while (condition) {}` and `do { } while(condition)` is when the condition is checked: before or after each iteration.  Usually, it's best to test the condition before you begin the first iteration, so you'd use a while loop.  But sometimes the loop body must be executed at least one, in which case a do-while loop is appropriate.

In the example you provided, the most convenient place to check when it's time to exit the loop is in the midst of an iteration (specifically, in case 3 where the return statement will exit the loop and the function.)

With these types of loops, the choice is largely up to the programmer's style.  Any of these would have worked:

```cpp
do {
    // loop body here
} while (true);
```

```cpp
while (true) {
    // loop body here
}
```

```cpp
for (;;) {
    // loop body here
}
```

The for-loop case works because the initialization, condition, and increment expressions are all optional.  If the condition is omitted here, it's the same as if you had said `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In the given example, the author of code has implemented a loop, given `true` as the value of loop *expression* which means the loop will keep on iterating and when user will enter `3`, the function (in which this loop is implemented) will return `0` and exit.

From [do-while loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do) *[emphasis added]*:

> Executes a statement repeatedly, until **the value of expression becomes false**. The test takes place after each iteration.

> Syntax
> attr (optional) do statement while ( **expression** ) ;

*expression* is defined as:

> expression    -   **any expression which is contextually convertible to bool**. This expression is evaluated after each iteration, and **if it yields false, the loop is exited**.

---

Additional:

From C++20#6.8.1 [Fundamental types]:

> 10 Type bool is a distinct type that has the same object representation, value representation, and alignment
> requirements as an implementation-defined unsigned integer type. **The values of type bool are true and
> false.** [Note: There are no signed, unsigned, short, or long bool types or values. — end note]